Using IDisposable to dispose an AVAudioPlayer
I am new to IDisposable and trying to figure out what I am doing wrong in my MAUI app. I have the following code where I initialize an AVAudioPlayer, and methods to Play and Dispose (irrelevant methods are disregarded below).
IVoicePlayer inherits IDisposable
public class VoicePlayer : IVoicePlayer
{
    AVAudioPlayer player;
    private bool isDisposed;

    public VoicePlayer(byte[] audioBytes)
    {
        var data = NSData.FromArray(audioBytes);
        player = AVAudioPlayer.FromData(data)
                 ?? throw new Exception("Unable to create AVAudioPlayer from data.");

        //player.EnableRate = true;
        player.PrepareToPlay();
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        isFinishedPlaying = false;
        player.Play();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (isDisposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Stop the player and release the resources
            // if (player != null)
            // {
            //     if (player.Playing)
            //     {
            //         player.Stop();
            //     }
            //     player.Dispose();
            //     player = null;
            // }

            player.Stop();
            player.Dispose();
        }

        isDisposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Destructor to catch cases where Dispose was not called
    ~VoicePlayer()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}

My issue is that when I use VoicePlayer as follows in my ViewModel, the audio never plays - when I have breakpoints in the Dispose method, it plays the audio while I'm waiting to step in, this makes me think that Dispose is getting called before the audio even gets a chance to play out of Debug mode.
using (var voicePlayer = new VoicePlayer(record.Bytes))
{
    voicePlayer.Play();
}

But if I execute without the using statement it plays fine, but it seems the destructor is never called so the player is never released.
var voicePlayer = new VoicePlayer(record.Bytes);
voicePlayer.Play();

What I am trying to figure out is a way to Dispose the player once playback finishes.

There's a FinishedPlaying event you can try like so...
Add a method to handle the event...
void HandleFinishedPlaying(object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) 
{
    DisposeAudioPlayer();
}

Straight after the player is initialised, wire up the handler to the event...
player.FinishedPlaying += HandleFinishedPlaying;

Define a method to dispose the player on the main thread...
void DisposeAudioPlayer()
{
    if (player == null)
        return;

    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        player.Stop();
        player.FinishedPlaying -= HandleFinishedPlaying;
        player.Dispose();
        player = null;
    });        
}


After the Play() method executes, the using block exits, which automatically calls .Close and .Dispose on the object.
Using objects that implement IDisposable:
"The using statement in C# and the Using statement in Visual Basic simplify the code that you must write to cleanup an object. The using statement obtains one or more resources, executes the statements that you specify, and automatically disposes of the object. However, the using statement is useful only for objects that are used within the scope of the method in which they are constructed."

In your case, you state: "What I am trying to figure out is a way to Dispose the player once playback finishes."
In order to accomplish this, you need to have code that recognizes when the playback is finished. I'm not familiar with this library directly, but it appears that you could do something like:

Implement an IsPlaying property that returns true if the player is playing
Create a loop that waits for the player to stop
When the loop exits, dispose of the player

For example:
Implement an IsPlaying property
public class VoicePlayer : IVoicePlayer
{
    AVAudioPlayer player;
    private bool isDisposed;

    public bool IsPlaying => player?.Playing() ?? false;

    // Other implementation omitted

}

Loop and wait for player to stop before disposing
using (var voicePlayer = new VoicePlayer(record.Bytes))
{
    voicePlayer.Play();
    
    // Wait for player to stop
    while(voicePlayer.IsPlaying);
}

If you want your application to be responsive to other things while the player is running, then it might be better to store the player object as a class field and then dispose of it when your class is disposed or launch the player in a separate thread (which would be a different question, I think).

If I make this an async/await player would it help? Not the biggest fan of the while loop cause that’s a blocking activity I feel.

Yes, of course, this was just an example to get you started
